# Spring Kafka consumer not able to connect to broker

Tags: java, apache-kafka

I am trying to do Kafka consumer configuration using ssl enable but not able to connect.
I have used Spring boot 2.3.3.RELEASE and respective Kafka-client & Spring Kafka was pulled by parent dependency.
Here is some code snippet -

```
    Map<String, Object> config = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    config.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, kafkaBootStrapServers);
    config.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
    config.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
    config.put(ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG, "true");
    
    if (sslEnabled) {
        config.put(SslConfigs.SSL_PROTOCOL_CONFIG, "SSL");
        config.put(SslConfigs.SSL_TRUSTSTORE_LOCATION_CONFIG, trustStoreLocation);
        config.put(SslConfigs.SSL_TRUSTSTORE_PASSWORD_CONFIG, trustStorePassword);
        config.put(SslConfigs.SSL_KEY_PASSWORD_CONFIG, keyStorePassword);
        config.put(SslConfigs.SSL_KEYSTORE_PASSWORD_CONFIG, keyStorePassword);
        config.put(SslConfigs.SSL_KEYSTORE_LOCATION_CONFIG, keyStoreLocation);
    }
```

I am  getting below warning with above config which keeps on writing the logs every seconds.

```
groupId=dp-cds-consumer-group] Bootstrap broker sd-5ea4-f0b6.apac.nsroot.net:9093 (id: -2 rack: null) disconnected
2021-06-02 16:30:09.791  WARN 447 --- [Container-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.NetworkClient                    : [Consumer clientId=consumer-dp-cos-consumer-group-2, groupId=dp-cos-consumer-group] Bootstrap broker sd-1c3f-5bcc.apac.nsroot.net:9093 (id: -1 rack: null) disconnected
2021-06-02 16:30:10.005  WARN 447 --- [Container-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.NetworkClient                    : [Consumer clientId=consumer-dp-etrs-consumer-group-3, groupId=dp-etrs-consumer-group] Bootstrap broker sd-5ea4-f0b6.apac.nsroot.net:9093 (id: -2 rack: null) disconnected
2021-06-02 16:30:10.283  WARN 447 --- [Container-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.NetworkClient
```

Instead of `config.put(SslConfigs.SSL_PROTOCOL_CONFIG, "SSL");` if i use `config.put("security.protocol", securityProtocol);` then i am getting below exception :-

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No enum constant org.apache.kafka.common.security.auth.SecurityProtocol.SSL.SECURITY.PROTOCOL
```

Kindly suggest if some more config is missing here to be added to resolve the issue.

Comment: sslEnabled is set to true? Your "if" gets executed?

Comment: The logs provided not enough to understand the error, please provide more log files